# MacBook Air freezes when disconnected from ASUS monitor

Tags: macbook-pro, display, performance

MacBook Air M2, Ventura 13.5. When I disconnect (unplug from) ASUS external monitor, my laptop becomes non-operational; neither keyboard nor trackpad respond.

I have to shutdown while connected to external, reboot, disconnect external, then restart. Sometimes twice. Then laptop works, however, if I shut the lid, and go back to using the laptop (without monitor) everything is frozen again.

My old MacBook Pro does not have this problem. Is there a setting?

Comment: There’s no setting for this, but I am curious to know what would happen if you plugged in a USB keyboard and mouse  (for testing purposes).  The built-in keyboard/trackpad go through the T2 chip so I am wondering if there’s an issue there.  Can you test this out?